# Spring Boot with Spring Session and Redis - RedisConnectionFactory is required

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-session

I am setting up a Spring Boot app that uses:

- OAuth2 Login
- Spring Session for authentication
- Redis for the session storage

Using this spring boot application.yaml to enable redis:

```yaml
spring:
  session:
    store-type: redis
    redis:
      namespace: sample:api
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
```

And the following SecurityConfig:

```java
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig<S extends Session> extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RedisIndexedSessionRepository redisIndexedSessionRepository;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement()
                    .maximumSessions(1)
                    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
                .and()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests(a -> a
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
                .oauth2Login()
                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                    .and()
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:3000/users")
                    .authorizedClientRepository(authorizedClientRepository())
                ;

    }

    /**
     * enables session expiry notification
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }


    @Bean
    public SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry<>(this.redisIndexedSessionRepository);
    }

    /**
     * Use the servlet container session store for authorized OAuth2 Clients
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository() {
        return new HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository();
    }
```

When I start the application, it fails with the following:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'redisIndexedSessionRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/RedisSessionConfiguration$SpringBootRedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisIndexedSessionRepository]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.RedisSessionConfiguration$SpringBootRedisHttpSessionConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'sessionRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: RedisConnectionFactory is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1598) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1562) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1451) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.resolveMethodArguments(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionRepository' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/session/RedisSessionConfiguration$SpringBootRedisHttpSessionConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisIndexedSessionRepository]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.RedisSessionConfiguration$SpringBootRedisHttpSessionConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'sessionRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: RedisConnectionFactory is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:486) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 108 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisIndexedSessionRepository]: Circular reference involving containing bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.RedisSessionConfiguration$SpringBootRedisHttpSessionConfiguration' - consider declaring the factory method as static for independence from its containing instance. Factory method 'sessionRepository' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: RedisConnectionFactory is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 121 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RedisConnectionFactory is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisAccessor.afterPropertiesSet(RedisAccessor.java:38) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet(RedisTemplate.java:128) ~[spring-data-redis-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.createRedisTemplate(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:291) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.config.annotation.web.http.RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.sessionRepository(RedisHttpSessionConfiguration.java:120) ~[spring-session-data-redis-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 122 common frames omitted
```

This exception goes away when I remove the `SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry` session registry, however so does the ability to control the max number of sessions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it turns out that the culprit is the `HttpSessionEventPublisher`. The sessionRepository (which we can see at the top of the stack trace complaining about the circular dependency) for Redis (`RedisHttpSessionConfiguration`) extends `SpringHttpSessionConfiguration` which injects a list of all `HttpSessionListener` beans registered, which includes the `HttpSessionEventPublisher`

Put that in its own `Config` class:

```java
@Configuration
public class HttpSessionEventPublisherConfig {

    /**
     * enables session expiry notification
     *
     * Needs to be declared separately from the `SpringSessionBackedSessionRegistry` to avoid a cir
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }

}
```

And it all magically works.

Comment: Why put it in its own config class? Why not just declare the bean in an existing config class?

Comment: I only had 1 config class (ie the one with sessionRepository), I mean it doesn't need to go in its own class, just a different one from the sessionRepository

Comment: Why does it need to be in a different config than sessionRepository? As long as the bean is declared in a config class or even in the application class, it should be fine. It shouldn't need to be physically segregated from other beans.

Comment: If its in the same class, it creates a circular dependency. The `HttpSessionEventPublisher` bean needs to be 
 instantiated before the sessionPublisher

Comment: I just ran into this again (on the same project) this time with a `CookieSerializer` (finally got around to doing logout). Anything that's a dependency to the session publisher needs to be created early, so the `CookieSerializer` bean also needs to be created in the static / other class as well.